# Is my javascript closure written correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am using the following function closure in a jqgrid (a jquery grid) to retain changes in edits when paging in a variable called 'retainedChanges'- does this look ok; Im i breaking any good practices in javascript;
the code works alright just want to make sure I dont introduce features that can break in the future

```
 (function($){
      var retainedChanges;
      retainedChanges = new Array();
      $.retainChangesOnPaging = function(){
        var changedCells = $('#grid').jqGrid('getChangedCells');
        // loop over changedCells array, removing duplicates if you want to...
          return  retainedChanges.push(/* this is inside the loop; push current value to array*/);
         ....
      }
       $.getRetainedChanges = function(){
         return retainedChanges;
       }
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why don't we combine the first two lines of your function to become `var retainedChanges = [];`?

Comment: Some suggestions: Use `[]` instead of `new Array()` and don't store things in the jQuery object unless they are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine, although you should probably accept jQuery as an argument:

```
(function($){
```

This way, even if the `$` symbol is being used for something else outside of your closure, it won't effect your code inside the closure.

2 more things:

1) You should declare and assign you variable together, and use `[]` instead of `new Array()`.
2) You're missing a `$` symbol here: `('#grid')`.

---

For a full rundown, look at this:

```
(function($){

  var retainedChanges = [];

  $.retainChangesOnPaging = function(){
    var changedCells = $('#grid').jqGrid('getChangedCells');
    // loop over changedCells array, removing duplicates if you want to...
    return  retainedChanges.push(/* this is inside the loop; push current value to array*/);
    ....
  }

  $.getRetainedChanges = function(){
    return retainedChanges;
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yeah I had that in the original code - just added it here - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `jQuery` into a function that has no arguments and never uses the jQuery object passed in. You may have meant:

```
(function($){
```

Other than that it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could improve:

1) You pass `jQuery` to the function, but do not use it (you use **global** object `$`, if it is defined). Modify your code to **accept one parameter, named `$`**:

```
(function($){
```

2) You can **shorten `retainedChanges` declaration**:

```
var retainedChanges = new Array();
```

3) If you are trying to **write jQuery plugin**, then follow the following tutorial: [jQuery: Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

If not, then maybe use different global object than `jQuery`?